# Second monitor doesn't work on an Intel GM965

Tags: 11.04, video, display

I have  Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c) and when I plug a vga or HDMI cable I can't see the second monitor and the I only see a mess main monitor, like this screenshot http://ubuntuone.com/p/rBo/.

Comment: The screenshot link does not work: "Could not locate object".  I suggest http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 1):

I often use a second monitor with my laptop, which has an Intel GM965 video card.  Usually it works fine, sometimes it fails in one of the two ways:

- Both screens freeze and nothing happens, I can't interact with the system.  Forcefully killing the GUI session with Alt+SysRq+K helps.
- One of the screens is fully or partially obscured by a black rectangle; I can see the mouse cursor, but I cannot see my desktop or any windows.  Restarting Compiz or Unity fixes this; I usually do Alt+F2 `unity` Enter.

VGA hotplug detection works for me in 11.04 (it didn't in 10.10 or earlier versions), so it's enough for me to plug in a monitor and wait about a second for it to be autoconfigured.  If this doesn't happen for you, or if Ubuntu's chosen autoconfiguration (cloned display versus extended desktop) is not to your liking, you can run `gnome-display-properties` ("Monitors" in the GNOME Control Center) and specify what configuration you'd like to have.

I don't have a HDMI connection on my laptop, so I cannot say from personal experience if there are any bugs affecting HDMI.